# Preventing FOUC when calling CSS through a javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, fouc

I have a webpage which I have altered from a template. I am suffering from FOUC (Flash of Unstyled Content).

I have tried a solution from here: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1jt_VQC5LDF-e9j8Wtxu4KZPa8ItlmYmntGy5tdcbGOY/present?slide=id.p

but could not get it to work.  Here is a main part of my head, the scripts are calling my CSS in (I think!).

```
<head>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="top">
            bunch of stuff to hide until style has loaded. 
</body>
```

The idea of this solution is to pause the load of the content until the CSS has loaded, but I am not sure whether it will work when calling with a java script.

Here is what I tried:

```
<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        #fouc { display: none; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.documentElement.className = 'js';
    </script>

    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>

</head>

<body id="top">

    <div id="fouc">
            bunch of stuff to hide until style has loaded. 
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("fouc").style.display="block";
    </script>

</body>
```

This did not work. Can anyone suggest a way to stop the FOUC in this scenario?

Thank you for your patience, I appreciate the help,

J

Comment: This is a genuine question, if people are going to down vote me they can at least comment why.

Comment: I didn't down vote, but here's a few random thoughts. Most of the time it's best to put your script tags before the closing `</body>` tag and css, whether internal or external, gets loaded in the `<head>` section. Also you are using `.js #fouc`. I don't see this doing anything because what you are saying there is that you are looking for the id of fouc inside a class of js, which I don't see `class='js'` anywhere in that HTML. So just use `#fouc` there.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have edited the above to match my code but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my solution:

```
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>

     <style type="text/css">
       .no-fouc {display: none;}
     </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.documentElement.className = 'no-fouc';
     $(window).on("load", function() {
        $('.no-fouc').removeClass('no-fouc');
     });    
    </script>
```

This whole thing went into the <head> with no changes to the <body>.

Which rather than using classes and id's in the body section, uses $(window).on("load", function() to only load the page once the content is loaded. be sure to load jQuery *before* the script block.